# SSIS “Save Copy of …” missing in my Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I want to move my SSIS package to a new SQL Server.  To accomplish that I installed MS SSDT for VS 2017 successfully on my dev laptop.  I opened the SSIS project (which worked fine in VS 2015 on my old dev laptop). I opened the package and went to the file menu hoping to fine 'save a copy of' but it is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears 'save as' is not the way to do it anymore.  You need to right click the package and select 'deploy', but before I could do that I had to install and reconfigure the environment because my packages hadn't been migrated from sql2014 to sql2016 AND my visual studio 2017 didn't have ssis package support installed and configured. see unsupported below

[image: unsupported]

[image: install ssdt]

then you have to convert the deployment model
[image: convert]

[image: conversion complete]

then right click the package and save to ssis package on sql 2016.  but it didn't work because I hadn't condigured ssis on sql server
[image: save to ssisdb]

create a ssis db on sql server
[image: save the package]

now you can deploy the package
[image: deploy the package]

And that will work if your package doesn't use project variables.  but if you use variables and converted to project deployment (like I did) then you need to deploy a bit differently because your individual package wont deploy with the project level variables.  In this case, You need to click the 'project' item on the menu bar and then click 'deploy' from the DDL.  This will deploy all your packages and project variables at once, which is nice.  This means that my dtsconfig xml configuration file is no longer in the loop, i.e., its been replaced by the project params.  Its also nice because you don't need to manually create the ssis db on sql server, i.e., the project-deploy creates it for you .

Comment: OK this is really strange, but today my "Visual Studio SSDT" link doesn't work.  It worked in the past, but when I click the link it pulls up regular Visual Studio and says that my SSIS project is incompatible....groan

Comment: Ok, fixed the solution incompatible issue.  If you right-click on your solution in SSDT, you have an option call "Reload Project" and that did it for me.